# Test Rig Azure Controller cannot connect to Visual Studio Client

Tags: windows, azure, performance-testing

I am deploying a test rig as per the directions from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh674491.aspx with the controller and agents hosted on windows azure. I have followed all the directions properly and my VS client is able to see the controller and agents. However when i execute a load test, the test remains in an pending state and I see the below error in the Controller's eventlog. My problem is similar to one found at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazureconnectivity/thread/4040619f-5667-4445-804a-84f37d823c9f/. Please help!

(QTController.exe, PID 692, Thread 11) ControllerDeployment.DoDeployment: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond [xxx:xxx:xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:220]:6915

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket(EndPoint ipEndPoint)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketCache.GetSocket(String machinePortAndSid, Boolean openNew)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.SendRequestWithRetry(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.FileCopyService.get_DeploymentFlags()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerExecution.b__6(FileCopyService fileCopyService)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.RemoteObjectContainer`1.InvokeAsRemoteUser(Action`1 invoke)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerExecution.DoDeployment()

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message it looks like the controller is not able to talk to the agent. Have you set up a connect group as mentioned below:
"http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh674497.aspx"
Creating a Connect Group
The Connect feature of Azure allows you to create a Virtual Private Network. Members of the group can include on-premise computers as well as Azure role instances. **For the Load Test solution, the Connect group allows communication between the test controller and the agents.**

Comment: Yes I have setup a connect group. And the on-premise machine and the azure worker roles (controller & agent) are a member of the controller group. In the error message the value '[2a01:111:f102:129:2c4d:d497:7d75:220]' matches my machines address so that means the Controller is unable to connect to the on-premise machine. Also I am able to telnet from the controller to the agent and vice versa.

Comment: Have you created a local user(corresponding to the user specified in the controller) and running your on-premise visual studio as this user?
"http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh674481"
Creating a Local User To Manage a Load Test Controller

Answer (score 0):

Attempted this as well, and couldn't get it to work. Ended up having to move the Controller into Azure as well.

I followed the documentation as far as what ports the agent needed, and opened those up in the Azure firewall. However, after doing a network capture, IIRC it also used some dynamic ports that weren't going to work to open up.

So I found that I had to move Visual Studio, the Load Agent Controller, and the Load Agents themselves all into Azure to utilize this in the cloud.